# Not getting response from REST API in Android

Tags: android, laravel, android-volley

I created a Volley JsonObjectRequest, which makes a HTTP Request to my REST API. But after calling, it's not responding with any Json.

```
     String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.10.136:8000/api/vehicle";
     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(JSON_URL,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
            try {
                JSONArray vehicles = response.getJSONArray("vehicles");
                for (int i=0;i<vehicles.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject vehicle=vehicles.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(vehicle.getString("type")=="Taxi") {
                        TaxiList sr1 = new TaxiList();
                        sr1.setName(vehicle.getString("name"));
                        sr1.setPhone(vehicle.getString("phone"));
                        results.add(sr1);
                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

My REST API is built using Laravel 5.2

Their is no error displayed during execution. After execution the log window has the following messages:

```
01-14 10:23:44.011 1050-1079/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal D/Volley: [121] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://192.168.10.136:8000/api/vehicle 0x31e08304 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=4372], [size=804], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
01-14 10:23:44.538 1050-1050/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 6690 ms: [ ] http://192.168.10.136:8000/api/vehicle 0x31e08304 NORMAL 1
01-14 10:24:16.518 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.407ms
01-14 10:24:31.773 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.889ms
01-14 10:24:40.305 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.920ms
01-14 10:24:41.283 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.850ms
01-14 10:24:52.957 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 83.792ms
01-14 10:24:58.775 1050-1050/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
01-14 10:24:59.828 1050-1053/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30.584ms
01-14 10:25:00.767 1050-1050/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
01-14 10:25:01.763 1050-1058/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1634(113KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(26MB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 1.513ms total 188.700ms
01-14 10:25:03.514 1050-1058/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.173ms
01-14 10:25:03.625 1050-1058/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25(1168B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 19MB/23MB, paused 1.341ms total 100.224ms
01-14 10:25:04.494 1050-1058/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.538ms
01-14 10:25:04.661 1050-1050/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal I/Choreographer: Skipped 243 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-14 10:25:08.349 1050-1050/com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal I/Choreographer: Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I need help to fix this problem

Comment: Never used volley. But your logcat says you are getting response

Comment: You should put a log the response first then check what is response from server then start mapping according to json

Comment: try Log.i("tag", "Response= " + response); inside onResponse() and post the response.

Comment: also check your request

Comment: on my error log got; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObjec

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify what you want volley to do with the URL,whether a Get request or Post request.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,JSON_URL,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(
{
});
```